# Angular 12 Server-side rendering (SSR) with Angular Universal Cannot match any routes error

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I have a basic Angular 12 App with a navbar and a home and contact components. I want to apply SSR to this app for SEO so that all the pages (Home and Contact) HTML are generated.

[image]

I ran the following command: `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`

Then I ran the following command: `npm run dev:ssr`

The app opens, but SSR didn't work, because when I click on the View Page Source the HTML have not been rendered.

How do I solve this issue?

*Edit:
Here is my angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angularTemplate": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angularTemplate/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angularTemplate:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "angularTemplate:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angularTemplate:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angularTemplate/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractLicenses": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "angularTemplate:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "angularTemplate:server:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angularTemplate:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "angularTemplate:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angularTemplate:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "angularTemplate:server:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "angularTemplate:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "angularTemplate:server:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "angularTemplate"
}
```

Comment: the part `angularTemplate/src/assets/images/SleekLogo-white%20transparent%20-140x70-Tiny.png` of the stacktrace is strange. Looks like angular is trying to resolve an image as if it was a route. Can you first remove spaces from this image, or check where do you use this image (to see if it is not used is a strange place ?). Also, can you show you angular.json file, where you define the assets folder ?

Comment: Okay so I sorted out the image and the error is gone. I ran the command again to enable SSR and then ran dev:ssr and it works without any error, but when I click View Page Source then the HTML has not been generated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "View Page Source" ? Can you have a look in the "network" tab ? The first call (which should be something like `localhost:4200/`, should countain the HTML code. Can you show its content ?

Comment: I'm always using `npm run start:ssr`

Comment: When you right click on any website and your select "View Page Source" then it will give you the Raw HTML code of the website. That is what I mean. (In Chrome). npm run start:ssr script doesn't exist. I don't get anything in the network tab.